# How to convert/Format HTML Markup to text inside a word document

Tags: html, ms-word

I have a word document, and in this document I have some HTML markup. So How can I  convert/format these html markup to text.I tried with Macro but .docx file cannot save macro, so need to change the file type but I can not change the file type  because I have to provide the docx file as a template(.docm & .dotm not supported in Dynamics 365). Please see below example.

Example:

In my word document I have below markup

```
<ul>

<li><strong> Computer </strong></li>

<li><strong> Laptop</strong></li>

<li><strong> PC</strong></li>

</ul>
```

I want to convert/format like this

- Computer
- Laptop
- PC

Is there any way to do this with Word Add-In or any other way?

Comment: Look at leveraging the Office Open XML file format. MS provides the Open XML SDK as a tool that can takes care of "unzipping" the "package" and builds an object model around the XML content.

Answer (score 0):

Docx files are actually .cabs behind the hood.

You can change your docx file extension to .cab, extract it, and try and make your way through the xmls there to add custom formatting.